# installing nuget from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, nuget

My Dockerfile has the next command:

```
RUN apt-get install -y nuget
```

Yet, I get the next message:

[image]

Is there a way to automatically pass all those related questions?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  For this particular question, you can find several other instances of it by pasting the text of the prompt into the Stack Overflow search box, but you can't easily copy that text out of an image, or find an image in search results.